# C++ Turkish string problem with setlocale

Tags: c++, windows, setlocale

I want to find Turkish characters from the user's input. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");
    string input;
    string chars = "çığöşü";
    cout << "Input: ";
    getline(cin, input);
    cout << "Turkish Characters: " << chars << "\n";
    cout << "Your input: " << input;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I get this:

```
Input: çığöşü
Turkish Characters: çığöşü
Your input: ┼?§"Y?
```

If I don't use `setlocale`, I get this:

```
Input: çığöşü
Turkish Characters: ²­÷■³
Your input: çığöşü
```

I used `wstring`, but it didn't change anything. I want to get some text from user and try to find Turkish characters in text using my chars string. Is there an easy way to do this? (I'm using Windows)

Answer (score 1):

If your system language is not Turkish, then `"çığöşü"` is compiled as English or whichever settings you have, it will match as a different set of characters in Turkish. Unless in your compiler settings you change the code page for *.cpp file to Turkish. Otherwise you have to use `L"çığöşü"` and convert that to the right ANSI code page.

Use `SetConsoleCP/SetConsoleOutputCP` with code page `1254` to print Turkish. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

std::string ansi(wchar_t* wbuf, int codepage)
{
    int len = WideCharToMultiByte(codepage, 0, wbuf, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    std::string shortname;
    shortname.resize(len, L'\0');
    WideCharToMultiByte(codepage, 0, wbuf, -1, &shortname[0], len, 0, 0);
    shortname.resize(len - 1);
    return shortname;
}

int main()
{
    int codepage = 1254;
    SetConsoleOutputCP(codepage);
    SetConsoleCP(codepage);
    std::cout << ansi(L"çığöşü\n", codepage);
    std::string input;
    std::cout << "Input: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    std::cout << input << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Unicode is recommended (not this uses `_setmode` which visual Studio specific)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <io.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::wcout << L"çığöşü\n";
    std::wstring input;
    std::wcout << "Input: ";
    std::getline(std::wcin, input);
    std::wcout << input << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
string changeTrCharacters(string text){
    replace (text.begin(),text.end(),-108,111); // ö to o
    replace (text.begin(),text.end(),-103,79);  // Ö to O
    replace (text.begin(),text.end(),-127,117); // ü to u
    replace (text.begin(),text.end(),-102,85);  // Ü to U
    replace (text.begin(),text.end(),-115,105); // ı to i
    replace (text.begin(),text.end(),-104,73);  // İ to I
    replace (text.begin(),text.end(),-89,103);  // ğ to g
    replace (text.begin(),text.end(),-90,71);   // Ğ to G
    replace (text.begin(),text.end(),-97,115);  // ş to s
    replace (text.begin(),text.end(),-98,83);   // Ş to Ş
    replace (text.begin(),text.end(),-121,99);  // ç to c
    replace (text.begin(),text.end(),-128,67);  // Ç to C
    return text;
}
```

In main function, change `cout << "Your input: " << input;` line with `cout << "Your input: " << changeTrCharacters(input);`